# Como fazer para somar as linhas de um vetor bidimensional e mostrar o resultado da soma de cada linha?

Tags: java, array, matriz, soma

```
 for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++) {
            soma += vetor[j][i];
           }
           System.out.print("Aluno " + (i + 1) + " : ");
           System.out.println(soma + " ");
       }
```

Comment: Só por um `soma = 0` no inicio do primeiro `for`

Answer (score 0):

Se for o que eu entendi, é só você zerar o "soma" após ler cada linha, ou guardar em um vetor a soma de cada linha.

```
public class vetor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int soma = 0;

        int vetor[][] = new int[5][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++) {
                vetor[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++) {
            soma+=vetor[i][j] = 1;
            }
            System.out.println(soma);
            soma=0;
        }
        
    }

}
```

### caso com vetor:

```
public class vetor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int soma[] = new int[5];

        int vetor[][] = new int[5][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++) {
                vetor[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++) {
            soma[i]+=vetor[i][j] = 1;
            }
            System.out.println(soma[i]);
        
        }
        
    }

}
```